# Отправка запрос при помощи axios вместо jQuery

Tags: javascript, axios

Не знаю как сделать,что бы при вводе в инпут ip оно отправляло запрос на сайт и возвращало уже данные именно по тому ip что я написал. 
И подскажите,как переписать не json, а использую axios.

```
function f1(){
    $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
        var q = document.getElementById('four');
        var table_body = "";
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            table_body += "<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td><b>" + v + "</b></td></tr>";
        });
        $("#GeoResults").html(table_body);
    });
```

}

```
  <input name="four"  type="text" onblur="f1()">
  <table id="GeoResults"></table>
```

Comment: Вы хотите переписать выполнение запроса с jQuery на axios?

Comment: А в чем сложность то?

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю что не получается то?

Answer (score 1):

```
function f1(){
var q = $('#four').val();
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/" + q + "?callback=?", function(data) {

    var table_body = "";
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        table_body += "<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td><b>" + v + "</b></td></tr>";
    });
    $("#GeoResults").html(table_body);
});
}
<input id="four"  type="text" onchange="f1()">
<table id="GeoResults"></table>
```

Comment: Как с jQuery на axios этого не знаю(

Comment: Походу помогло, причем тут axios не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

```
function f2(){
        var q = $('#fice').val();
        var resultElement = document.getElementById('getResult1');
        resultElement.innerHTML='';
            axios.get("http://ip-api.com/json/" + q + "?callback=?")
                .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response);
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
            resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(error);
        });
    }

    function generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response){
        return response.data
    }

<input id="fice"  type="text" onchange="f2()">
<div id="getResult1"></div>
```